# Which iterator(other than for, foreach) can be used to count the number of character in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, loops

I dont know what iteration method to be used for more efficiency, Here i have listed my solution which i have tried. is there any other way to iterate, i mean any special methods or ways?

Method One :

Here i have used two for loops so the iteration goes for 2N times

```
public void CountChar()
{
    String s = Ipstring();
    int[] counts = new int[256];
    char[] c = s.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; ++i)
    {
        counts[c[i]]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c[i].ToString() + " " + counts[c[i]]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Method 2 :

```
public void CountChar()
{
    _inputWord = Ipstring();
    char[] test = _inputWord.ToCharArray();
    char temp;
    int count = 0, tcount = 0;
    Array.Sort(test);
    int length = test.Length;
    temp = test[0];

    while (length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
        {
            if (temp == test[i])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(temp + " " + count);
        tcount = tcount + count;

        length = length - count;
        count = 0;
        if (tcount != test.Length)
            temp = test[tcount];
        //atchutharam. aaachhmrttu
    }
}
```

Method three:

```
public void CountChar()
{
    int indexcount = 0;
    s = Ipstring();
    int[] count = new int[s.Length];
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        Console.Write(c);
        count[s.IndexOf(c)]++;
    }

    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (indexcount <= s.IndexOf(c))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.WriteLine(count[s.IndexOf(c)]);
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        indexcount++;
        ////atchutharam
    }
}
```

Comment: nope, number of steps is 2xN so complexity is O(N) <- you can't get better here than O(N)

Comment: In method 1, a char can be >= 256 so you need to handle that.

Comment: Also, you don't need `ToCharArray()`. `for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i) { counts[s[i]]++; }` should work, too. Or `foreach (char c in s) { ... }`

Comment: Btw.: defining a character as indexer of an array isn´t a good idea - although it represents an integer. The resulting array would have too much NULL-values in an arbitrary order. Better use a list where you put your characters in...

Comment: @wudzik what about the other methods??

Comment: @Ram 3rd method is same as 1st -> different syntax, I don't understand 2nd it looks really bad. I suggest you to use dictionary instead, I can post some code if you want.

Comment: @wudzik yeah you can post your code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ methods to group the characters and count them:

```
public void CountChar() {
  String s = Ipstring();
  foreach (var g in s.GroupBy(c => c)) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", g.Key, g.Count());
  }
}
```

Comment: I was just going to add same answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are not nested so your complexity is not N*N (O(n^2)) but 2*N which gives O(N) because you can always ignore constants :

```
for(){}
for(){} // O(2N) = O(N)

for()
{
    for(){}
} // O(N*N) = O(N^2)
```

If you really want to know which one of these 3 solutions have the fastest execution time in a specific environment, do a benchmark.

If you want the one that is the most clean and readable (And you should almost always aim for that), just use LINQ :

```
String s = Ipstring();
int count = s.Count();
```

It will execute in O(N) too.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the results in arrays:

```
var groups = s.GroupBy(i => i ).OrderBy( g => g.Key );
var chars = groups.Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();
var counts = groups.Select(g => g.Count()).ToArray();
```

Otherwise:

```
var dict = s.GroupBy(i => i).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

foreach (var g in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine( "{0}: {1}", g.Key, g.Value );
}
```

Comment: var testString = Ipstring();
        testString.ToCharArray()
       .OrderBy(h => h).ToLookup(e => e)
       .Select(e => new { character = e.Key, count = e.Count() }).ToList()
       .ForEach(j => Console.WriteLine("letter {0}, count {1}", j.character, j.count));